# Disable backtick autocompletion in sublime

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm working with sublime 3 (build: 3143) and I experience a really annoying issue since a long time.

Whenever I type a backtick

> `

it is automatically completed to a pair of quotes

> `'

this is annoying especially when I want *only one* of the two symbols, and I'm not able to find what I did or wasn't able to prevent in order to obtain this higly undesirable behaviour.

I suspect this is something LaTeXTools is doing; no clue of what I shall disable (auto-completion? But then I'd lose autocompletions I need, and like, too).

Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You're right, [this is a keybinding from LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools/blob/6fe2473b283584a3c75547e5c7a36513a6e83b30/Default%20(Linux).sublime-keymap#L408-L415):

> ```
> // autopair quotation marks (`')
> { "keys": ["`"], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "`$0'"}, "context":
>     [
>         { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
>         { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
>         { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
>     ]
> },
> ```

To remove this behavior, as there is no LaTeXTools preference for it, one can simply add a new keybinding in the User keybindings file to override it, that will simply insert a backtick:

```
{ "keys": ["`"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "`"}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "text.tex.latex"},
        { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```